# The inverse of the matrix $\{1/(i+j-1)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, hilbert-matrices

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2 & 1/3 & \cdots & 1/n \\
1/2 & 1/3 & 1/4 & \cdots & 1/(n+1) \\
\vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1/n & 1/(n+1) & 1/(n+2) & \cdots & 1/(2n-1)
\end{pmatrix}$$

is invertible and all the entries of its inverse are integers. This is an exercise in Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: [Hilbert matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Comment: @user17762 Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430060/why-does-the-inverse-of-the-hilbert-matrix-have-integer-entries?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

[The matrix you have is a Hilbert matrix.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) The $(i,j)$ entries of its inverse are given by
$$(-1)^{i+j}(i+j-1){n+i-1 \choose n-j}{n+j-1 \choose n-i}{i+j-2 \choose i-1}^2$$which are clearly integers.