# Proving that an matrix have integers entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Considering the Matrix below with $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \frac{1}{2} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1} \\
 \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \cdots & \frac{1}{2n-1} \\
 \end{array} \right) $$

How i show that this matrix is invertible and $A^{-1}$ has only integers entries using some elimination method , like for example Gauss-Jordan?
I tried to prove that $A$ is invertible, but i consider very difficult to solve the problem on this way and using this approach i have no idea how to prove that the entries are integers.

Comment: Hilbert matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the inverse of the Hilbert matrix have integer entries?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430060/why-does-the-inverse-of-the-hilbert-matrix-have-integer-entries)

Comment: I see this question, but that use the idea of a Cauchy matrix, and a want to see something more easy, maybe the calculation using the Gauss-Jordan

Comment: @ExampleMo OK, if you want to have these restrictions then you *must* make sure they're clear in the problem statement, or else someone else is going to cast closing votes. (I've retracted mine at the moment.)

Comment: Ok i will reformulate the question