# On invertibility of a special matrix - Hilbert matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I want to know how to prove that the below matrix is invertible

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  & ... & \frac { 1 }{ n }  \\ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  & \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  & ... & \frac { 1 }{ n+1 }  \\ ... & ... & ... & ... \\ \frac { 1 }{ n }  & \frac { 1 }{ n+1 }  & ... & \frac { 1 }{ 2n-1 }  \end{pmatrix}

and that the inverse matrix has integer entries.

Comment: I believe this is a known matrix with a wiki article. Can't remember its name, though. This has also been asked before.

Comment: I think it is called Hilbert matrix.

Comment: Try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Hilbert+matrix) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix). If you happen to find your question, please add a comment here so we can mark it as a duplicate. I suggest you add the name 'Hilbert Matrix' to the title somewhere.

Comment: Another [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/430060/73025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the the article on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) with this matrix.

Comment: The problem came in the first chapter of a linear algebra book which I am trying to work through. They didn't mention the name of the matrix. Thanks for the link!