# Finding the closed form of the determinant of the Hilbert matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, hilbert-matrices

In my studies of matrix theory I came across the famous Hilbert matrix, which is a square $ n \times n $ matrix $ H $ with entries given by: $ h_{ij} = \frac{1}{i+j-1} $ and this is an example of a Cauchy matrix, which is a matrix $ C_n $ of the form $ c_{ij} = \frac{1}{x_i+y_j} $ and for this matrix there is the well known formula for the determinant:

$$\det(C) = \dfrac {\displaystyle \prod_{1 \mathop \le i \mathop < j \mathop \le n} \left({x_j - x_i}\right) \left({y_j - y_i}\right)} {\displaystyle \prod_{1 \mathop \le i, \, j \mathop \le n} \left({x_i + y_j}\right)}$$

Now I think I can substitute the sequences for the Hilbert matrix but I cannot see how to get [the closed form they got here (under Properties)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix):

$$\det(H) = \frac{c_n^4}{c_{2n}}$$

where

$$c_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} i^{n-1} =\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} i!$$

and I was hoping someone would please help me obtain the closed form. Thanks.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47561/deriving-inverse-of-hilbert-matrix, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430060/why-does-the-inverse-of-the-hilbert-matrix-have-integer-entries

Comment: It seems the Question is not asking about the formula shown in the body above, but about a different "closed form" given only in the section of the Wikipedia article linked to.  The Question would therefore be substantially improved by directly stating that formula here, allowing Readers the benefit of its clarity.

Comment: @hardmath : I have done so, thank you and sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to accept the use of special functions, then there is an explicit closed form for the determinant of the $n\times n$ Hilbert matrix $\mathbf H_n$. Using the expression for the $\mathbf D$ factor of the $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ decomposition shown in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47583) (and originally derived by [Hitotumatu](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03167904)), one can multiply together the diagonal elements of $\mathbf D$ (and then recall that $\det \mathbf L=1$) to get

$$\begin{align*}
\det \mathbf H_n&=\det\mathbf D=\prod_{k=1}^n \frac1{(2k-1)\tbinom{2k-2}{k-1}^2}\\
&=\frac{G(n+1)^4}{G(2n+1)}
\end{align*}$$

where $G(n)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\Gamma(k)$ is the [Barnes $G$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function).

Answer (score 1):

To find the determinant of the $n\times n$ Hilbert matrix, we will apply a sequence of row operations (multiplication on the left) and column operations (multiplication on the right) that will transform the Hilbert matrix into a diagonal matrix.

The Hilbert matrix is $H_0$ where the element in row $j\in[1,n]$ of column $k\in[1,n]$ of $H_m$ is given by
$$
h_m(j,k)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\frac1{j+k-1}&\text{if $j=k$ or ($j\gt m$ and $k\gt m$)}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag1
$$
for example, for $n=5$,
$$
H_0=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & \frac12 & \frac13 & \frac13 & \frac15 \\
 \frac12 & \frac13 & \frac14 & \frac15 & \frac16 \\
 \frac13 & \frac14 & \frac15 & \frac16 & \frac17 \\
 \frac14 & \frac15 & \frac16 & \frac17 & \frac18 \\
 \frac15 & \frac15 & \frac17 & \frac18 & \frac19
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
H_2=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac13 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac15 & \frac16 & \frac17 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac16 & \frac17 & \frac18 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac17 & \frac18 & \frac19
\end{bmatrix}\tag2
$$
etc.

For a given $m$, we will use element $(m,m)$ in $H_{m-1}$ as a pivot to clear out the rest of column $m$ using row operations and the rest of row $m$ using column operations.

For a given $m$, subtracting $\frac{2m-1}{j+m-1}$ times row $m$ from row $j$ in $H_{m-1}$ multiplies row $j$ by $\frac{j-m}{j+m-1}$ (left multiplication) and column $k$ by $\frac{k-m}{k+m-1}$ (right multiplication); that is,
$$
\frac1{j+k-1}-\frac{2m-1}{j+m-1}\frac1{k+m-1}=\frac{j-m}{j+m-1}\frac{k-m}{k+m-1}\frac1{j+k-1}\tag3
$$
Thus, if we define $T_m$ and $D_m$ by
$$
\begin{align}
t_m(j,k)&=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1&\text{if $j=k$}\\
-\frac{2m-1}{j+m-1}&\text{if $j\gt k$ and $k=m$}\\
0&\text{if $j\gt k$ and $k\ne m$ or $j\lt k$}
\end{array}\right.\tag{4a}\\
d_m(j,k)&=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1&\text{if $j=k$ and $k\le m$}\\
\frac{j+m-1}{j-m}&\text{if $j=k$ and $k\gt m$}\\
0&\text{if $j\ne k$}\\
\end{array}\right.\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
$(3)$ yields
$$
H_m=D_mT_mH_{m-1}\left(D_mT_m\right)^T\tag5
$$
Since $T_m$ is a lower triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal,
$$
\det(T_m)=1\tag{6a}
$$
Although we won't use it, it is not difficult to see that
$$
\det(D_m)=\binom{n+m-1}{n-m}\tag{6b}
$$
What we will use is that since
$$
\prod_{m=1}^nd_m(j,k)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\binom{2j-2}{j-1}&\text{if $j=k$}\\
0&\text{if $j\ne k$}\\
\end{array}\right.\tag7
$$
we get
$$
\det\left(\prod_{m=1}^nD_m\right)=\prod_{j=1}^n\binom{2j-2}{j-1}\tag8
$$
Iterating the determinant of $(5)$ and applying $\text{(6a)}$, we get
$$
\left(\prod_{m=1}^n\det(D_m)\right)\det(H_0)\left(\prod_{m=1}^n\det\left(D_m^T\right)\right)=\det(H_n)\tag9
$$
Applying $(8)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\det(H_0)
&=\left(\prod_{m=1}^n\frac1{\det(D_m)}\right)\det(H_n)\left(\prod_{m=1}^n\frac1{\det\left(D_m^T\right)}\right)\tag{10a}\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac1{\binom{2j-2}{j-1}^2(2j-1)}\tag{10b}
\end{align}
$$