# Determinant of special matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, hilbert-matrices

Consider the following matrix of harmonic series.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1/1 & 1/2 & \ldots & 1/n \\
1/2 & 1/3 & \ldots & 1/(n+1) \\
&\ldots& \ldots &\\
1/n & 1/(n+1) & \ldots & 1/(2n-1) \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I would like to know the form of its determinant.
Or, if the determinant is not easy to express, can one show that it is non-zero?

Comment: This is known as a [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891043/339790

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you, Integrand and Rodrigo.